# What all are the other options to optimize spark memory consumption. and where/why does Spark eats so much of memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on an issue where I am facing a spark memory error or disk failure issue.

Right now we are working with GBs of data where we need to extract data from the source and transform using spark and store it in a database. Also soon, I am going to work with TBs of data.

Problems occur when I read 1GB of data spark needs a max of 4GB of memory to process it and then throws an error like disk failure or out of memory etc.

I have researched and tried several ways to optimize spark:

- Cache and persist
- Data Serialization
- Memory Management
- Data Frames over RDD
- Data Structuring
- Creating Chunks (to a limit unless it will make the program slower by a lot. and not be feasible in TB's data )
- And all the configurations I found on the internet rather its regarding spark memory fraction or else.

But none of the above techniques helped me much. I want to know why spark eats so much of memory.

I have read Spark memory Structuring where Spark keep 300MB for Reserved memory, stores sparks internal objects and items. 25% for user memory and the rest 75% for Spark Memory for Execution and Storage Memory. But still Don't understand why spark needs 4GBs of memory to process 1GB of data.

Comment: The way you posed your question is a little bit too broad for here. We can only know why Spark eats so much memory if you share a minimal reproducible example of your code, cluster configuration details and error stack trace. Don't feel discouraged by this though! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can read up on how to ask a good question :)

Comment: It would also be useful if you provide code of what you are trying to do once you read  that 1GB of data

Comment: I am working as an Inter in a company, So I am allow to see and Share the code @koedlt and Vindhya

Comment: You can share a sample code or more of what you are trying to do Does it have aggregation etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@vndhya/stateful-processing-in-spark-structured-streaming-memory-aspects-964bc6414346

We were facing memory issues similar to yours too. So this is the article  where i have added whatever we found out while trying to fix it. Note that this is for structured streaming and might not be relavant for batch jobs or streaming jobs.